# Page not redirected laravel 7

Tags: laravel

i am creating simple crud application on laravel.once the data added page should redirect to index page.but not redirected. what i done so far i attached below.

after add the record page redirected i wrote like this way
**Controller**

```
   public function index()
{
    $students = Student::all();
    return view('index', compact('students'));      
}  
public function create()
{
    return view('create');
} 
public function store(Request $request)
{
    Student::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'phone' => $request->phone,
        'address' => $request->address,
        'created_at' => now(),
    ]);
    $student->save();
    return redirect()->route('students.index')->with('success', 'Student has been added');
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::post('/', 'StudentController@index')->name('student.index');
```

i got the error was **Undefined variable: student**

index.blade.php full code here

```
@extends('layout')
 
@section('content')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 margin-tb">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <h2>Laravel 7 CRUD Example from scratch - ItSolutionStuff.com</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right">
            <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ route('student.create')}}"> Create New Student</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   
    @if ($message = Session::get('success'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <p>{{ $message }}</p>
        </div>
    @endif
  
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Address</th>

        </tr>
  
        @foreach ($students as $student)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $student->id  }}</td>
            <td>{{ $student->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $student->phone }}</td>
            <td>{{ $student->address }}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </table>

      
@endsection
```

Comment: you can simply change to `any` `Route::any('/', 'StudentController@index')->name('student.index');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have error here `$student->save();` when you using `create()` don't need to save

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    Student::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'phone' => $request->phone,
        'address' => $request->address,
        'created_at' => now(),
    ]);
   
    return redirect()->route('students.index')->with('success', 'Student has been added');
}
```

Comment: return redirect()->route('student.index')->with('success', 'Student has been added'); i put like this sir show same error Undefined variable: student

Comment: @haridran check now

Comment: now working sir. again i want to do the pagination how to add it on the index page sir please help

Answer (score 0):

You cannot redirect to `POST` route. You need to change the route verb to `GET`

Comment: Route::get('/', 'StudentController@index')->name('student.index');  i put like this again show the Undefined variable: student

Comment: edit your post and add the code for the `index` method in `StudentController`

Comment: You reference `student` but the variable name is `students` in the controller. The error seems to be coming from the `index.blade.php` view. Edit your post and add your `index.blade.php`  view code

Comment: i added the index.blade.php